# How to install SQLite Entity Framework 1.0.99.0 by nuget command

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

Currently SQLite has version 1.0.101.0. But its visual studio design time installer has trojen (as windows defender showing on windows 10 OS).

So, I want to install SQLite Entity Framework 1.0.99.0 in my visual studio 2013, winform project. This version has correct design time installer also.

I tried this command in package manager console.

```
install-Package System.Data.SQLite -version 1.0.99.0
```

and the result is the following.

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Data.SQLite.Core (≥ 1.0.99.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq (≥ 1.0.99.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 (≥ 1.0.99.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 6.0.0)'.
Installing 'System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.101.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.101.0'.
Installing 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.101.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.101.0'.
Installing 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.0.0'.
Installing 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.101.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.101.0'.
Installing 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.99.0'.
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.99.0'.
Adding 'System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Successfully added 'System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Adding 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Successfully added 'System.Data.SQLite.Linq 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Adding 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' to QuotMaster.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 6.0.0' to QuotMaster.

Type 'get-help EntityFramework' to see all available Entity Framework commands.
Adding 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Successfully added 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6 1.0.101.0' to QuotMaster.
Adding 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.99.0' to QuotMaster.
Successfully added 'System.Data.SQLite 1.0.99.0' to QuotMaster.
```

It is installing the latest version. I am unable to install 1.0.99.0 version. I want to know how can I install this specific version.

Comment: If someone down votes this question then please add comment why you down vote  this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this solution, enter this command in package manager console.

```
install-package System.Data.Sqlite.Core -version 1.0.99.0
install-package System.Data.Sqlite.EF6 -version 1.0.99.0
install-package System.Data.Sqlite.Linq -version 1.0.99.0
```

this installed SQLite entity framework 6 - 1.0.99.0

Comment: Worked for installing 1.0.105.0 con Visual Studio 2015.